# Rails, Bootstrap, trying to dynamically load modal does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

OK I have a link to modal in html, which works perfectly.
As you can see the link in there also, but I don't need it in my app.

```
<div class="block">
    <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button" href="#editor-modal">Run modal with WYSIWYG editor</a>

    <!-- Modal with WYSIWYG editor -->
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="editor-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-quill2"></i> WYSIWYG editor inside modal</h4>
                </div>



                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /modal with WYSIWYG editor -->

</div>
```

Instead of having a ton of modals in my app, I want to load them dynamically.

I tried to define a placeholder and load the modal there and then show it.
I have done this a couple of times, but this time it does not work for some reason.

So in my **index.html.erb** I got

```
<div id="modal-placeholder" class="block"> </div>
```

I got my partial **_addNewModal.html.erb**:

```
<!-- Modal with WYSIWYG editor -->
<div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="editor-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-quill2"></i> WYSIWYG editor inside modal</h4>
            </div>



            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /modal with WYSIWYG editor -->
```

And I load it with the following code.

```
$('#modal-placeholder').html("<%= j render 'news/modals/addNewModal'%>")
$('#editor-modal').modal('toggle');
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. I tried to replicate the html code from my template, but for some reason it does not work.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** 
As I checked, the *modal-placeholder* actually is filled with the data, but the modal does not show up.I tried both

```
$('#editor-modal').modal('toggle');
```

&

```
$('#editor-modal').modal('toggle');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **j render** by default search for a `js.erb` file

When rendering partials inside Javascript code, you should use the **escape_javascript** method, like so

`$('#modal-placeholder').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'news/modals/addNewModal') %>");`

If you explicitly declare the `partial` key then it will search for your `html.erb file instead of js.erb`

So try either the above command or this.

`$('#modal-placeholder').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'news/modals/addNewModal') %>");`

For the toggling, remove inline `display: none;` from the form and add a style for it,

```
#editor-modal
 {
   display: none;
 }
```

Then the toggle will work.

```
$('#editor-modal').toggle();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, as I checked right now it loads the data, either with my code or yours, but the 'toggle' does not work. I will edit the question.

Comment: remove `display:none` from inline and add it in the styles,
`#editor-modal
{
 display: none;
}`, then toggle also will work.

Comment: Still does not work. Seem like a problem reading the bootstrap.min.js.
It does not change the class, display and such, like with the html template I got. Any ideas on that?

Comment: let us debug it, add `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`, in that view page for testing

Comment: Thank you so much. I was loading the the bootstrap.min.js from my assets, but after trying to load from the online source it worked. I guess it did not load, even though I required it.